# Error when connect to server AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have this code below i'm trying to send a data to a server but the only documentation i have to connect to it is a sample data post to the server it looks like this `{“method”:“fruit-post”,“data”:{“red-fruits”:["Apple","Cherry","Tomato"],“green-fruits”:["Grapes","Watermelon"],“yellow-fruits”:["Lemon","Pear"],“purple-fruits”:[]}}` Am i doing anything wrong here for my code below becuase i keep getting an Error 405 and `Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405.` Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
var fruitData = {};

var key = "red-fruits";
fruitData[key] = red;

var key2 = "green-fruits";
fruitData[key2] = green;

var key3 = "yellow-fruits";
fruitData[key3] = yellow;

var key4 = "purple-fruits";
fruitData[key4] = purple;

var fruitString = JSON.stringify(fruitString);

$.ajax({
    method: "fruit-post", 
    type: "POST",
    url: "LINK",
    data: {
        "data": fruitString
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
}
```

Comment: `fruit-post` isn't a valid method value, it must be GET, POST, PUT, DELETE or any of the possible values. `url` is also not a valid link. If you want to make a request to your backend, just add the url for its endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ajax request is wrong. Look here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

method has to be `POST`,`GET` or `PUT`

```
$.ajax({
  url: "LINK",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
        “method”:“fruit-post”,
        “data”:{
            “red-fruits”:["Apple","Cherry","Tomato"],
            “green-fruits”:["Grapes","Watermelon"],
            “yellow-fruits”:["Lemon","Pear"],
            “purple-fruits”:[]
        }
  },
  dataType: "html",
  cache: false,
      success: function(data) {
  }
});
```

Comment: And for the `"method": "fruit-post"` in the sample post data what is that for?

Comment: maybe like this, i dont know depends on your api

Answer (score 0):

ajax uses method `type:'get'` or `"post"` no need of `method` mention you method in url

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "LINK",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
         "data": fruitString
    },
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
  }
 });
```

Comment: can you post your web method ..?